# know if (and how) my vertices were reordered

Tags: c++, box2d

C++, Box2d 2.3 game development happening here.

TL;DR: just read the bold text.

After creating a **`b2PolygonShape`**, I can set the vertices of the shape with the **`Set()` function**, which takes an array of `b2Vec2` objects and a count. [In the documentation of that function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQlqe.png) there is a **warning saying that the vertices may be reordered** even if they form a convex polygon.

Now, I render the fixtures using the vertices in their shapes. I'm currently implementing UV mapping; I have a vector of UV points corresponding only by order with the original vector of vertices. If the vertices get reordered, the vector of UVs will not match up, and there will be rendering errors. **How can I know if and how the vertices have been reordered, so that I can reorder my UV points in the same way?**

For clarification, the resulting order I'm referring to is the one as retrieved from `b2PolygonShape.GetVertex()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any official way to do this, so, short of modifying the source code, the only option seems to be to **store the vertices yourself and render from your own list**, instead of querying Box2D on rendering. Notice that this gives you more artistic freedom too; you can render a fixture in a way that doesn't have to be exactly as it is physically simulated (say, a character with horns or a tail that you don't want to partake in the siumulation).

Comment: Right. Generally the debug draw is not used for the final display of your game :)